# Function calling multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listing HTML structure is below

```
<li class="game-box showlist" id="papp_1249" data-tag="Junior KG,Maths">
  <div class="game-box-link" 
       data-id="1249" data-active="yes" data-orientation="landscape" 
       data-ajax="false" data-url="http://totsmart.in/scale_concept" 
       data-transition="none">

    <img src="http://example.com/abc.jpg" class="game-thumb">
  </div>
  <div class="game-title">
    <div class="btn-container">
      <a href="#login" class="box-btn4">
        <img src="css/assets/Login.png">
      </a>
      <div class="box-btn4 price-btn">
        //clicking this using trigger
        <span class="game-price buy" data-id="">Free</span>
      </div>
      <span class="sm_box-btn expand">
            <img src="css/assets/drop.png">
        </span>
      <div data-id="1249" data-active="yes" data-orientation="landscape" 
           data-ajax="false" data-url="http://example.in/scale_concept" 
           data-transition="none" class="game-box-play-link sm_box-btn">

        <img src="css/assets/Play.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="game-content">
      <p><strong>Subject</strong>: Maths
        <br>
        <strong>Class</strong>: KG – KG – Junior &amp; Senior
        <br>
        <strong>Description</strong>
        <br>Drag and drop objects to one out of the two empty boxes and practice the scale concepts like – Big-Small, Fast-Slow, Tall-Short etc.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div><span class="game-box-title">Scale concepts</span>
</li>
```

My JavaScript function is

```
$("body").on('vclick', '.game-box-link, .game-box-play-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var application_id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log('game-play-clicked');
    check_app(application_id, this);
});

check_app(application_id, item)
{
      alert('clicked');
      var game_id = $(item).data('id');
        if ("ios" != deviceType()) {
            $('#papp_'+game_id+' .buy').trigger("vclick");
            console.log('triggered');
        }
}
```

My problem is when I clicked on `game-box-link` div for first time then `check_app()` called for one time if i clicked it for second time  `check_app()` called for 2 times and so on. I need it to be called only one time. Where am I going wrong?

This is screenshot of my console log. You can see it fire for 7 times:

[image]

Comment: no i am not looping it.

Comment: `this` can not be accepted as `argument`..

Comment: Your function should looks like `function check_app(application_id, _this){ alert('clicked');}` begin with `function`.

Comment: if you are binding the `vclick` event via calling some function then it might registered a new `vclick` everytime.

Comment: Provide a fiddle where one could reproduce it...

Comment: there is lots of styling so its difficult to add fiddle

Answer (score 0):

add `e.stopPropagation();` to your function.

```
$("body").on('vclick', '.game-box-link, .game-box-play-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var application_id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log('game-play-clicked');
    check_app(application_id, this);
});

check_app(application_id, this)
{
      alert('clicked');
}
```

The click event on the child also happens on the parent, that's why the event is being triggered multiple times.

Comment: the parent element is `li`, are you sure it is happening?

Comment: still fired for multiple times

Comment: updated my question. please see it is due to trigger. Please take a look